# How to reuse Avro Map definition

Tags: avro

I have an Avro Schema record defintion that looks like this. It contains maps that restrict values

```
{
    "namespace": "MyNamespace",
    "type": "record",
    "name": "AvroObject",
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "entries1",
            "type": [
                "null",
                {
                    "type": "map",
                    "values": [
                        "null",
                        "long",
                        "string",
                        "boolean"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "default": null
        },
        {
            "name": "entrie2",
            "type": [
                "null",
                {
                    "type": "map",
                    "values": [
                        "null",
                        "long",
                        "string",
                        "boolean"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "default": null
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to extract the map defintion so it can be reused

```
{
    "namespace": "MyNamespace",
    "type": "map",
    "name": "MyMap",
    "values": [
        "null",
        "long",
        "string",
        "boolean"
    ]
}
```

The Avro Schema compiler let's me define records for reuse but complains about maps

```
  {
        "namespace": "MyNamespace",
        "type": "record",
        "name": "AvroObject",
        "fields": [
            {
                "name": "entries1",
                "type": "MyMap" <---------- NOT ALLOWED
            },
            {
                "name": "entries2",
                "type": "MyMap" <---------- NOT ALLOWED
            }
        ]
    }
```

How can I define a schema for a map?

Comment: What error do you get ?

Comment: Could not compile schema definition files:
  * src/avro/schemas/MyNamespace/AvroObject.avsc: "MyNamespace.MyMap" is not a defined name. The type of the "entries1" field must be a defined name or a {"type": ...} expression.

Comment: can you provide the way how you are compiling? Are you using avro maven plugin?